# Selecting VALUE from a datagridview based on COLUMN HEADER in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, identity-column

I have a datagridview with a SINGLE row.
The row is populated from a parent datagridview (from where I selected the single row).
The row has headers(cloned from the parent datagridview).

I know the name of the primary key column header.
 HOW DO I GET THE VALUE UNDER THE PRIMARY KEY COLUMN ?

On the net i found things like

```
...(row.Cells["xxx"].Value, 123)
```

OR

```
 string a = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["you have to mention you cell  corresponding column name"].Value);
```

OR

```
 string pk_col_val = Convert.ToString(grid_detail.CurrentRow.Cells[i].FormattedValue);
```

But none shows how to get what I want.

I need a way to get the value by NAME of the column not id.HOW?

Help ?

Answer (score 2):

second option looks OK if you want to select value by name of the column.

Or do you mean you only know text in the column's header? If so, then you can get id of your column, for example with linq:

```
string headerText = "find column's id with this header";
int id = this.DGV.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
         .Where(a => a.HeaderText.Equals(headerText))
         .FirstOrDefault().HeaderCell.ColumnIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your contributions guys.

I resorted to used the following and it solved my problem
The code I used goes as

```
   string pk_col_val = grid_detail[0, 0].Value.ToString();
```

Thnks.